Theorem 3.6.4 (Separable space) Kreyszig.
Kreyszig , in "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" , has this Theorem 3.6.4 (with Proof) concerning Separable spaces.
Theorem. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. If $H$ contains an orthonormal sequence which is total in $H$, then $H$ is separable.
Proof Let $(e_k)$ be a total orthonormal sequence in $H$ and $$A:=\text{span}_\mathbb{Q}(e_k)=\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n\gamma_k e_k\;\; |\; n\in\mathbb{N}, \Re(\gamma_k), \Im(\gamma_k)\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}.$$
Clearly, $A$ is countable. We prove that $A$ is dense in $H$ by showing that for every $x \in H$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $v \in A$ such that $\lVert x - v \rVert < \varepsilon$. Since the sequence $(e_k)$ is total in $H$ , there exists $\tilde{y} \in \text{span}(e_k)$ such that $\lVert x- \tilde{y}\rVert < \varepsilon/2$. Thus, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\tilde{y} = \sum_{k=1}^N \alpha_ke_k \in \text{span}(e_1,\dots, e_N).$$
In particular, $\lVert x - y \rVert < \varepsilon/2$ for the orthogonal projection $y$ of $x$ on $Y_N=\text{span}(e_1,\dots, e_N)$, then $$y = \sum_{k=1}^N \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k.$$
Hence we have $$\left\lVert x-\sum_{k=1}^N \langle x, e_k \rangle e_k\right\rVert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Since the rationals are dense on $\mathbb{R}$, for each $\langle x, e_k\rangle$ there is a $\gamma_k$ such that $$\lvert \langle x, e_k\rangle-\gamma_k \rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2N}$$ and then $$\left \lVert \sum_{k=1}^N[\langle x, e_k\rangle - \gamma_k]e_k \right \rVert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$
Hence $v\in A$ defined as $$v = \sum_{k=1}^N \gamma_k e_k$$ satisfies $$\lVert x - v \rVert < \varepsilon.$$

Question. Why go from $\tilde{y}$ to $y$? Is this thing necessary?
And if yes, why? And if not, why did the author consider it appropriate?

Thanks!
Edit For completeness, I also upload a photo of the page of the book in question, maybe I interpreted something wrong.



I do not like this proof. It can be done easier by observing that ${e_n}$ is an orthonormal basis. Then every element  $x\in H$ can be represented as $\sum \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n.$ Therefore the elements of the form $\sum_{n=1}^Na_ne_n,$ where $N\in \mathbb{N}$  and $a_n\in \mathbb{Q}\cup i\mathbb{Q}$ form a countable dense subset of $H.$

@RyszardSzwarcThanks for your interest. I would like to understand the reason for everything written in a book, I imagine that there is a motivation behind everything.

I do not see any motivation for going from $\tilde{y}$ to $y$  besides the fact that $|x-y|\le |x-\tilde{y}|.$ But it is not essential in the proof.

I have looked up the definition of the  total set in the textbook by Kreyszig. A set $M$ in a normed space $X$ is total if the linear span of $M$ is dense in $X.$ Theorem 3.6.4 (b) holds for any normed space. There is no need to restrict to inner product spaces and orthonormal subsets $M.$ Indeed assume $M$ is a countable total set in $X.$  WLOG we may assume that $\|m\|=1$ for any $m\in M.$ Fix $x\in X$ and  $\delta>0.$ There exist $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_n\in M$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $$ \left \|x-\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k m_k\right \|<{\delta \over 2}$$ There are $\beta_k\in \mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|\beta_k-\alpha_k|<{\delta\over 2n}.$ Then $$ \left \|x-\sum_{k=1}^n\beta_k m_k\right \|<\delta$$ Hence the set of all finite linear combinations, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q},$ of the elements of  $M$ is dense in $X.$ Clearly this set is countable.

So from what I understand, the fact of moving on to the projection is to underline the fact that the space is Hilbert and therefore we can talk about projection onto closed subspaces, in particular since the ek are orthonormal the projection onto $\text{span}(e_1\dots, e_N)$ can be written in that way.

I have no idea why the author restricted the theorem to Hilbert spaces. It is misleading in my opinion as it suggests that the inner product and the orthogonal projections are essential for this theorem to hold.
